# Extracting json response from http request on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, curl, continuous-integration, pipeline

I'm creating a CI for my app using jenkins

Below is an additional script I call after building my app

```
script{            
      sh 'curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test "https://api/upload" -F "file=@path"'
     }
```

Above script will return json response, how can I extract the ID field from json and store it on a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I got the ID from json response.

```
def response = sh(script: 'curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" https://api/upload', returnStdout: true)   
def responseObject = readJSON text: response
def ID = "$responseObject.id"
println("ID:  $ID")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it, not yet tested.

```
script{            
      sh 'ID=$(curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test "https://api/upload" -F "file=@path")'
      sh 'curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test" -F app_id=$ID  -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" https://api/tasks'
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the output to a variable with the help of `returnStdout:true`.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        script{            
          def output = sh returnStdout:true, script: '''
            curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test" \
              "https://api/upload" -F "file=@path"
          '''
          sh """
            curl -X POST -H "Authorization:test" -F app_id=$ID \
              -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" \
              https://api/tasks
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The variable is then replaced inside the double quotes.